# git, how get old version of a file without changing current directory

Tags: git

In my project I made some changes that nothing works now. I cannot find what I changed. However, I use git. I started do it just recently. I want get previous revision of a file without changing current directory. How can I do it?

Edit: I want reverse file to a particular revsion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see which files got changed:

```
git status
```

To undo changes to a particular file:

```
git checkout <<FileYouChanged>>
```

If you want to toss out all changes since the last commit:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Comment: You can use 'git checkout .' to undo changes in all files starting from the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can check what you changed with

`git status`

If you didnt commit yet you can just do

`git stash` or `git reset --hard HEAD`

If you did commit but want to keep your changes You can use the command below with x as number of commits you want to reset

`git reset --mixed HEAD~x`

If you did commit and you want to get rid of your changes do the command above with `--hard` instead of `--mixed`

However if you commited & want to get tid of your changes and pushed to an arbitary repository (pushed your changes to another server) dont forget to force push the repository with

`git push -f origin branch`

To just undo one file use

`git checkout filename`

Answer (score 0):

Also use

```
 git diff
```

to find out what those changes are